# Change the color of the type hint in coc.nvim's rust-analyzer

Tags: vim, rust, neovim

I want to change the color of type-hint in rust-analyzer.
Currently it looks like this, and it is very difficult to distinguish the type
What part of coc-vim do I need to edit to change the color of the type-hint?

[image: vim screen shot]

Answer (score 4):

On my setup of nvim, I had to customize `CocInlayHint`. Changing `CocRustTypeHint` or `CocRustChainingHint` strangely did nothing.

```
    hi CocInlayHint guibg=Red guifg=Blue ctermbg=Red ctermfg=Blue
```

Comment: Same on my machine, maybe it got changed? Other answers are from Feb/Apr 2022, yours is from Sep 2022.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple for vim or Neovim!

In the `init.nvim` or `.vimrc` file add following lines:

```
"For Types hint 
hi default CocRustTypeHint guibg=Red guifg=Blue ctermbg=0 ctermfg=71
"Others hint 
hi default CocRustChainingHint guibg=Red guifg=Blue ctermbg=0 ctermfg=8
```

ctermbg=x and ctermfg=x where x = referentes a color number in Xterm Colors
guibg=x and guifg=x where x = referentes a color name in Neovim Colors

To view the currently applied style for these items, in the editor, type:

```
:hi CocRustTypeHint
```

or

```
:hi CocRustChainingHint
```

Answer (score 0):

It's `CocRustTypeHint`, by default links to `CocHintSign`, you can custom it in your vimrc.

https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-rust-analyzer#highlight-group