# How to make the `CocInlayHints` background color transparent in `.vimrc`

Tags: rust, vim, rust-analyzer, inlay-hints

This is a follow up question to [Change the color of the type hint in coc.nvim's rust-analyzer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71198499/change-the-color-of-the-type-hint-in-coc-nvims-rust-analyzer)

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the background color of inlay hints from Rust Analyzer in Vim. Adding a hex `#ffffff00` doesn't seem to work, nor does just `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more experimenting I was able to find that if you just remove the option for a background color in the examples provided in the aforementioned question, it will not have a background as desired. For me, that looks like:

```bash
"For Types hint
hi default CocInlayHint ctermfg=71
```

The part to remove is `ctermbg=0`. I also removed other parts from the example provided but it seemed to have no effect so I've left them out here as well.