After upgrading neovim to 0.10, coc-flutter has started displaying parameters types in a weird way
After installing the latest neovin version (0.10), I can see extra pointers of variables names.
That's what I mean
enter image description here
So when I open a file all looks good and after loading the coc-flutter extension, these things appear.
It comes exactly with neovim 0.10, I tried installing manually all previous versions, and there are no these things there. And doing this I didn't touch any packages or coc extensions.
Also I tried to find any mentioning such a feature in the release description but didn't find anything useful.
My problem is they look exactly like named parameters and it's very confusing.
It's worth to mention as well that changing colorscheme is not solving the problem.
I'd accept the following solutions:

changing color of these pointers (and or style, turning them into something like this [object])
removing them completely

Update 23.05.2024
Actually I've found the following advice, which partially solves my problem.
Name of highlighting property is CocInlayHint
I can't change what these hints look like but at least I can change color for them.
Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/73827297
Additionally there is a way to switch them off completely, adding the following line to the coc-settings.json file.
"inlayHint.enableParameter": false,

In my particular case I have switched them off, I don't find these hints useful working with Flutter.

Are you using neovim in terminal? Are you using some commands or autocommands to change ctermbg? If yes, try also changing guifg.

I'm using neovim in terminal.
Most of highlighting rules are covered by dart-vim-plugin and colorschema (I'm using dracula in dark mode)
Additionally I had to add some extra rules, but this one (see last update of my question) were missed

Neovim 0.10 turns on terminal colors by default. This changes the behavior of some plugins in terminal. You can revert to the old behavior by turning it off explicitly with set notermguicolors in init.vim.
See here for details: Neovim 0.10 colorscheme changes affecting background highlighting autocommands
